# What do the abbreviations in POS tagging etc mean?

Tags: language-agnostic, nlp, stanford-nlp

Say I have the following Penn Tree:

```
(S (NP-SBJ the steel strike)
 (VP lasted
     (ADVP-TMP (ADVP much longer)
               (SBAR than
                     (S (NP-SBJ he)
                        (VP anticipated
                            (SBAR *?*))))))
 .)
```

What do abbrevations like `VP` and `SBAR` etc mean? Where can I find these definitions? What are these abbreviations called?

Comment: The answers are all helpful as a starting point, but is there any resource that explains the meanings (with a short example or otherwise) beyond breaking down each acronym to few words, for those who don't hold a fresh memory of things like subordinate conjunctions and can't afford breaking context into wikipedia on every step?

Comment: This is (essentially) a duplicate of [Java Stanford NLP: Part of Speech labels?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833252/java-stanford-nlp-part-of-speech-labels). We should close this question and point people to that resource -- it is better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those are the Penn Treebank tags, for example, VP means "Verb Phrase". The full list can be found [here](http://web.mit.edu/6.863/www/PennTreebankTags.html)

Comment: The link mentioned above, http://bulba.sdsu.edu/jeanette/thesis/PennTags.html, is currently broken.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. Here's a new link with the same content courtesey of archive.org http://web.archive.org/web/20130517134339/http://bulba.sdsu.edu/jeanette/thesis/PennTags.html

Answer (score 0):

The full list of Penn Treebank POS tags (so-called tagset) including examples can be found on https://www.sketchengine.eu/penn-treebank-tagset/

If you are interested in detail information on POS tag or POS tagging, see a brief manual for beginners on https://www.sketchengine.co.uk/pos-tags/

Answer (score -3):

VP means verb phrase . these are standard abbreviation in the treebank.