# Where can I find the expansions for the short codes used by POS taggers?

Tags: nlp, nltk, opennlp

All of the Parts of Speech (POS) Taggers give the tags in the form of shortcodes like (NNS,VBZ etc).

> This/DT page/NN is/VBZ about/IN the/DT Brill-tagger/NNP

Like the above example which is from one of the [online POS Taggers](http://cst.dk/online/pos_tagger/uk/).

Where can I find the meaning of each shortcodes?

Comment: Duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853295/what-do-the-abbreviations-in-pos-tagging-etc-mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853295/what-do-the-abbreviations-in-pos-tagging-etc-mean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

English taggers often use the Penn Treebank Tagset.  Here you can find a [quick overview](http://www.ims.uni-stuttgart.de/projekte/CorpusWorkbench/CQP-HTMLDemo/PennTreebankTS.html) and the [official detailed annotation guidelines](ftp://ftp.cis.upenn.edu/pub/treebank/doc/tagguide.ps.gz).