# Stanford NLP pos tag PRN

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am using Stanford's CoreNLP pipeline. 
I am getting following TreeAnnotation:

```
(ROOT (S (NP (PRP I)) (VP (VP (VBP love) (NP (NN hepling))) (PRN (CC and) (ADJP (JJ willing) (S (VP (TO to) (VP (VB help)))))))))
```

Note: the sentence is grammatically incorrect, but this is intensional.

**What is "PRN" tag in TreeAnnotation?**

I did not find such tag in [Penn tags](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2007/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html) nor in [Stanford dependency tags](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dependencies_manual.pdf).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Stanford NLP: Part of Speech labels?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833252/java-stanford-nlp-part-of-speech-labels)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The labels can be over individual words (part of speech tags) or phrases (phrasal categories). `PRN` is a phrasal category for parenthetical phrases.

See [What do the abbreviations in POS tagging etc mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853295/what-do-the-abbreviations-in-pos-tagging-etc-mean/7853420#7853420) which will point you to a [full list](http://web.archive.org/web/20130517134339/http://bulba.sdsu.edu/jeanette/thesis/PennTags.html) of phrasal and part-of-speech tags.