# Set of POStag and Dependency labels inside CoreNLP

Tags: java, parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm working with the CoreNLP (Java), and I was just trying to find where the set of possible POStag labels are defined inside the code - in which class, enum or similar, I mean (if they are).

I would like to know the same for the Syntactic Dependencies as well.

I found this link here ([Java Stanford NLP: Part of Speech labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833252/java-stanford-nlp-part-of-speech-labels)), but it just says which is the tagset (that I already knew), but only to be consistent at all I would like to know if they are defined somewhere in the library structure.