# Stanford NLP: Arabic Part of Speech labels?

Tags: arabic, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I want to know the meaning of labels the **Arabic** part-of-speech tagger (2015.1.30 version) puts for each word.

like المدرسة/DTNN, I know it differs from the English tagger labels.

I searched their website and documentation but didn't find anything regarding the **Arabic standard labels**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Stanford NLP: Part of Speech labels?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833252/java-stanford-nlp-part-of-speech-labels)

Comment: @houssam I'm searching for the meaning of Arabic tagger labels not the English ones.

Comment: you are right, I thought they use the same tag set; I hope my answer is helpful for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I am not sure of this answer; but I hope it will help you.
What you asked for, must be located in the following link : [POS tag set does the parser use?](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-arabic-faq.shtml#d) (but unfortunately there are many broken links!!).
 
As they mentioned, you can find the tag set (you called labels) in the following file [atb1-v4.1-taglist-conversion-to-PennPOS-forrelease.lisp](http://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/docs/LDC2010T13/atb1-v4.1-taglist-conversion-to-PennPOS-forrelease.lisp). As I understand it, they map one or more sequence of English tags to one or more Arabic tag. for example:the mapping:

> (DET+ADJ_COMP+NSUFF_MASC_DU_GEN DT+JJR)

means that we map the English sequence of tags (DET+ADJ_COMP+NSUFF_MASC_DU_GEN) to the Arabic tags (DT+JJR). 
 
Regarding your question (المدرسة/DTNN), they mentioned that it consists of two tags (DT + NN) where DT= (الــ) (pronounced as 'Al')  and NN = (Noun, singular or mass) see [Penn Treebank](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/courses/Fall_2003/ling001/penn_treebank_pos.html) .

Answer (score 2):

They used a list of labels called a "POS list".

What they meant by "DTNN" is a determinant noun. For example, when you say in English "the girl is very beautiful", it's not the same as when you say "my girl is pretty".

Here is the POS list:

[image: POS list]