# What is the meaning of labels on the arrows of dependency parser graph?

Tags: label, stanford-nlp, dependency-parsing

I am using coreNLP module demo by Stanford online here: https://corenlp.run .
So, I am trying out a few sentences to see their syntactic structure using dependency parser available here. 
One such example is this sentence:

"documents related to new york industry that is export oriented and documents related to Indian history where Akbar is not fighting"

Its result is:
[image]

I am not able to understand the meaning of labels written on the arrows. I have got the list of labels to all the words here: [Java Stanford NLP: Part of Speech labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833252/java-stanford-nlp-part-of-speech-labels)

But where can I get a list of the labels on arrows/dependencies with their explanations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the definitions of dependency relations and their labels as used for English. When you click on a relation label, you'll get full explanation with examples.

https://universaldependencies.org/en/dep/index.html