# Stanford Java NLP Constituency labels abbreviations

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

Using the Stanford Java CoreNLP library, I have this:

```
            String text = "My name is Anthony";
            CoreDocument doc = new CoreDocument(text);
            pipeline.annotate(doc);
            for(Tree t : doc.sentences().get(0).constituencyParse()) {
                String tmp = "";
                for(Word w : t.yieldWords()) {
                    tmp = tmp + " " + w.word();
                }
                System.out.println(t.label().toString() + " - " + WordParts.getValue(t.label().toString()) + " - " + tmp);
```

Right now, the program outputs this:

```
ROOT - INVALID -  My name is Anthony
S - INVALID -  My name is Anthony
NP - INVALID -  My name
PRP$ - Possessive pronoun -  My
My-1 - INVALID -  My
NN - Singular noun -  name
name-2 - INVALID -  name
VP - INVALID -  is Anthony
VBZ - 3rd person singular present verb -  is
Subject:  Anthony
is-3 - INVALID -  is
NP - INVALID -  Anthony
NNP - Proper singular noun -  Anthony
Anthony-4 - INVALID -  Anthony
```

The `WordParts.java` abbreviations come from this post ([Java Stanford NLP: Part of Speech labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833252/java-stanford-nlp-part-of-speech-labels)) and the class file can be found here: (https://github.com/AJ4real/References/blob/master/WordParts.java)
I know that the labels are not `Parts of Speech` because some of the values return `INVALID`, so how can I find the full terms for the abbreviations that come from `t.label().toString()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rest are Penn Treebank phrase categories. E.g., see here:

https://gist.github.com/nlothian/9240750