# Extracting verb from german sentenceces

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, textblob, linguistics

I'm trying to extract verbs from German sentences. The problem is, for example in this sentence

`Ich rufe noch einmal an.`

Im getting rufe as the verb but its anrufe. I'm using textBlob and dont really know anything about linguistic. and using textblob I came accross POS tags. It tagged `an` as "RP"(doesnt know what that means) and `rufe` as "VB". I could just glue all "RP" and "VB" together but then again there could more than one verb in a sentence.

What is the right way of doing this?

Comment: Hello! What kind of data do you want to extract from data? Verbs list or verb phrases?

Comment: I want to extracts verbs in a given german sentence. using  textblob.download_corpora. Its a python pakage. I dont know if that helped

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `download_corpora` method is a part of `textblob` installation. Like in this example:

```
$ pip install -U textblob
$ python -m textblob.download_corpora
```

Then, you can use `textblob` for text analysis:

```
>>> test = TextBlob("Ich rufe noch einmal an.")
>>> test.tags
[('Ich', 'PRON'), ('rufe', 'VB'), ..., ('an', 'RP')]
```

More one interesting sub-library for German is here: https://pypi.org/project/textblob-de/

Maybe, this answer helps you to deep in POS-tagging, because your POS-tagger probably uses this universal tagset: [Java Stanford NLP: Part of Speech labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833252/java-stanford-nlp-part-of-speech-labels)

P.S. In German, word `an` is a part of verb. 'RB' is a participle. Hence, POS tags 'VB' and 'RP' related to the one verb.